# How do I get my EC2/RHEL to be accessible via a browser?

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, amazon-web-services

I've set up an instance on EC2 of RHEL (I also tried the same with a CentOS AMI) and cannot seem to connect via my browser.

I can SSH in.

But when I put the IP into my browser I can't connect.

I tried adding to the default Security Group Http. I tried adding Http to the new Security Group created when the instance was created, and I tried creating a new group as well...

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but can't seem to find any references to what it might be anywhere.

**EDIT**
Currently I have 3 security groups:

- quicklaunch-1: 
  **TCP** 
  22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0,
  80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0, 
  443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0
- default: 
  **ICMP**
  ALL sg-8adf34e1 (default)
  **TCP**
  0 - 65535   sg-8adf34e1 (default),
  80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0,
  443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0
  **UDP**
  0 - 65535   sg-8adf34e1 (default)
- Web: 
  **ICMP**
  Echo Reply  0.0.0.0/0,
  **TCP**
  0 - 65535   0.0.0.0/0,
  22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0,
  80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0,
  443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0
  **UDP**
  0 - 65535   0.0.0.0/0,
  53 (DNS)    0.0.0.0/0

I've tried with several different variations... same exact response.

Comment: What web server are you using?...

Comment: Apache, after the install I ran `yum install httpd` then `service httpd start`. I've been successful setting up CentOS 6 distros on VMWare... Haven't used EC2 yet.

Comment: Is there more info I can include that would help diagnose my problem?

Comment: You could tell us what happens when you try to visit the web site.

Comment: "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 54.225.70.96"

Comment: Did you open the port in the CentOS firewall?

Comment: Hmm, how would I do that? Sounds like that might be it...

Comment: is [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/) what you are referring to?

Comment: That was it!! Thank you! Please enter the formal answer so I can upvote you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the EC2 security group, your port 80 also needs to be opened in the CentOS firewall. You can use `system-config-firewall-tui` to do this from the root shell by selecting its **Customize** option.

[image: system-config-firewall-tui]